# Remoção indevida de tag

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edição

Não tenho certeza e por isso trouxe ao meta. Ao ver [esta edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/35289/revisions). Notei que a mesma é mínima e no meu ponto de vista incorreta. 
Tudo o que fora feito durante tal revisão foi a remoção da tag [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Que ao ver o título com JNI explícito (que é a parte do java para chamar funções em C) me parece que a tag C foi o mais próximo que o usuário pode colocar para a sua pergunta para decrever o problema.

Tal edição fora aprovada, uma vez que o usuário que a fez não possui ainda 1000 pontos.

Deveria reverter, minha pergunta é que o alt do reverter indica:

> define a revisão atual desta versão da publicação, redefinindo todos os sinalizadores "ofensivos"

Eu acho que foi um equivoco do usuário e não o queria penalizar revertendo, embora não sei se há alguma penalização significativa em tal ato.

Comment: Acho que cabe a tag jni, seja além de c ou no lugar dela. E não, reverter não penaliza ninguém.

Comment: JNI é fundamental. Então tem que escolher uma outra para ficar de fora. Qual a menos relevante? C?

Comment: Reverti e coloquei a tag JNI e voltei a C. Tirei netbeans por ser a menos relevante para pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, você já tomou as devidas providências, incluindo [jni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jni), reincluindo [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), e removendo a menos relevante. Esta resposta é para esclarecer o que significa o alt do link de reverter:

> define a revisão atual desta versão da publicação, redefinindo todos os sinalizadores "ofensivos"

Se houver algum sinalizador de que a pergunta é ofensiva, eles são eliminados. Não sei bem como funciona, mas espero que dependa da nova versão escolhida no momento da reversão. A intenção é tratar automaticamente esse tipo de sinalizador, pensando em casos em que a parte ofensiva foi justamente introduzida em uma edição (isso é relativamente comum, tem gente que troca o corpo da pergunta por xingamentos após receber votos contrários ou de fechamento).